# How to display name instead of the id?

Tags: php, html

[image]

I have problem, I don't know how to display the name of the department or program instead of their id. I am currently editing the user information but when I look to the department, the one who display it's id Here's my code for the editing:

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 form-group has-feedback">
<label class="control-label col-md-7 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Program</label>
        <select name="progid" class="select2_group form-control"  style="text-align:center;" >
//this part will calling the id
           <option><?php echo $rows['progid']; ?></option>
            <?php                                                   include('../connection/connect.php');
                $result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM program");
                $result->bindParam(':progid', $res);
                $result->execute();
            for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){
                echo "<option value='".$row['progid']."'>".$row['prog_name']."</option>";
                }
                    ?>
                    </select>
               </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your option tags you can set the attribute `value` to the value you want to sumbit to the next page via the form. This could be the ID for example. Between the tags you can add any textual content you like. This will then be displayed at the dropdown.

```html
<form>
  <select name="dropdown">
    <option value="id-1">Value1</option>
    <option value="id-2">Value2</option>
    <option value="id-3">Value3</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

The one ID which shows up in your department dropdown (7003) comes from this line:

```
<option><?php echo $rows['progid']; ?></option>
```

You either need to delete it and include it in your for loop or need to adapt to the previous example I have provided.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly:

In your code there is this line (line 5):

```
   <option><?php echo $rows['progid']; ?></option>
```

progId printed from here. remove this line or replace with progName.

If don't know how to find the prgname, you must find it from DB.

Comment: don't know how and where should I put it

Comment: try this: remove line 5. then replace line 7 with: `$result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM program where progid = :progid");`,  also chage line 8 to: `$result->bindParam(':progid', $progid);`

Comment: nothing will happened because of the <option><?php echo $rows['progid']; ?></option> because this is before the sql will put

Comment: @miming Oh a mistake was happed in changing line 8: `$result->bindParam(':progid', $rows['progid']);`. (in previous comment $progid is not defined).

Comment: **remove line 5** if you want `7003` do not show.
the structure of Database is unknown for we. If in your database there is row with progid=7003 and it have a special name, you should fetch it. To this end you must follow the above steps ( change line 7 and line 8)